# How to install extension via composer

Tags: magento-2.1

I've always installed extensions by default by putting all files in the directory.

I found a PDF generator which must be installed by composer.

```
https://github.com/EaDesgin/magento2-pdf-generator2?utm_source=mageplaza&utm_medium=mageplaza&utm_campaign=mageplaza-review&utm_content=Invoice
```

1. I have opened the SSH console in the magento root directory and try to run first command:

   composer config repositories.magento2-pdf-generator2 git git@github.com:EaDesgin/magento2-pdf-generator2.git

Unfortunately, get error:

- command not found

Can anyone help me how can I install this module by composer?

[image]

Comment: It seems composer is not installed on your system. 
so first you need to install composer then you can install plugin with composer.

Comment: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/comp-mgr/install-extensions.html useful link try this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use like below commands.

```
wget https://getcomposer.org/composer.phar
php composer.phar config repositories.magento2-pdf-generator
php composer.phar require eadesignro/module-pdfgenerator
```